# Pass data from one page to another in React using Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I am trying to pass only one string from a page to another using react router and **functional components only**, so I created a button that helps me link my 2 pages, but I am unable to pass my string.
This is my sample code on the initial page:

```js
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import React, { useState, Component } from "react";

function FrontPageDesktop() {
  const [myString, setMyString] = useState("Hello");
  return (
    <Link
      to={{
        pathname: "/donate",
        myString,
      }}
    >
      <TouchableOpacity> DONATE NOW </TouchableOpacity>
    </Link>
  );
}
```

And this is the code of the destination page:

```js
function DonatePageDesktop(myProps) {
  const { myString } = myProps.location.state;

  return <Text>Hello{myString}</Text>;
}
```

And thank you!

Comment: Your link object seems to be formatted incorrectly. Please read the documentation on it [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link/to-object). Also it seems that you may be using react-native. If so, the documentation link is [here](https://reactrouter.com/native/api/Link/to-object)

Comment: Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-link-state-liinu?file=/src/App.js). You have something else going wrong if it is still not working.

Comment: @BrianThompson , Yes it's a great example, but still, they are not working when putting each page in a separate file! Can you help me please?

Comment: Separate files don't matter. If you import them correctly then it will behave the same. If the imports were incorrect you would be getting a different type of error so that must be fine. I can't help any more without more information added to the question to illustrate the difference between your code and mine

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) you should pass the data using the `state` on the `Link` component:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import React, { useState, Component } from "react";

function FrontPageDesktop() {
  const [myString, setMyString] = useState("Hello");
  return (
    <Link
      to={{
        pathname: "/donate",
        state: myString,
      }}
    >
      <TouchableOpacity> DONATE NOW </TouchableOpacity>
    </Link>
  );
}
```

Comment: I got an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'myString' of null

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `state` key in the object which you pass to the `to` property of the `Link` component like this

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/donate",
    state: { myString }
  }}
>
  <TouchableOpacity> DONATE NOW </TouchableOpacity>
</Link>
```

Comment: I obtain the same error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'myString' of null